# NullPointer Exception setText()

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, settext

When I try to test my application my LazyAdapter class seems to have an error when it tries to assign text to a textView. Please help me. I don't know what is going wrong. Code seems to correct and Eclipse isn't showing me any errors in my structure. Thanks all

```
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public LazyAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<RowItem> items){
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        TextView fine;
        TextView courtApp;
        RelativeLayout card;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_element, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.card = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card);
            holder.fine = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fine);
            holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.description = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.courtApp = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.court_appearance);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            holder.title.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
            holder.description.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
            holder.fine.setText(rowItem.getFine());
            holder.courtApp.setText(rowItem.getCourtApp());

            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.card_animation);
            holder.card.startAnimation(animation);


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is the error that Logcat shows me.

```
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at com.gordondev.nyctlchackprep.LazyAdapter.getView(LazyAdapter.java:53)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2181)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1880)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:687)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:666)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:758)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1695)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2016)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:452)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1589)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:452)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:452)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1984)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1738)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1008)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5505)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
02-27 02:44:27.228: E/AndroidRuntime(21918):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 02:49:27.658: I/Process(21918): Sending signal. PID: 21918 SIG: 9
```

I figured out what was the problem. It was with the xml layout file. I was referring the wrong xml file. Special thanks to InnocentKiller.

Comment: so which line is line 53?

Comment: Yes line '53' should have mention in description.

Comment: Which `TextView` ? What's in line **53** in `LazyAdapter.java` ?

Comment: You have a null object on line 53.  We can not see which is line 53.  Please tell us.

Comment: Line 53 is 'holder.fine.setText(rowItem.getFine());' in the code. It is supposed to assign a String from an array of strings in another class.

Comment: I omitted a couple of lines including the package lines ...

Comment: Poast your `listview_element.xml` file also please/

Comment: InnocentKiller.. that was the issue. I was calling to the wrong xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private List<RowItem> items;
public LazyAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<RowItem> items){
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;this.items=items; }RowItem rowItem = items.get(position);
```